# TextOut() doesn't seem to exhibit a surrogate UNICODE pair

Tags: winapi, unicode

I tried to exhibit U+1D400 (surrogate pair `H = 0xD835` `L = 0xDC00`) using `TextOut()` to no avail. Why ?

> case WM_PAINT:

```
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;

    BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);

    int iLogPixelsY;

    iLogPixelsY = GetDeviceCaps(ps.hdc, LOGPIXELSY);

    LOGFONT lf;

    int iPts;

    iPts = 11;

    memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
    lf.lfHeight = -iPts * iLogPixelsY / 72;
    lf.lfOutPrecision = OUT_TT_ONLY_PRECIS;
    wcscpy_s(lf.lfFaceName, L"Cambria Math");

    HFONT hFont;

    hFont = CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject(ps.hdc, hFont);

    wchar_t tx[2];

    tx[0] = 0xD835;
    tx[1] = 0xDC00;

    TextOut(ps.hdc, 10, 100, tx, 1); 

    DeleteObject(SelectObject(ps.hdc, hFont));

    EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    break;
```

Comment: Do you have the fonts needed for that character?

Comment: The Cambria Math font is installed on my machine. I'm using the Word Equation Editor all the time.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling TextOut specifying a string length of 1, but according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145112%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), you should pass 2 since it is a surrogate pair.

Comment: this is right. You pass the number of characters rather than the number of code points.

Comment: @David: pass the number of words rather than the number of characters (it's one character, defined using two words).

Comment: No it really is characters. A surrogate pair of two characters make up a single code point. Microsoft's terminology is just wrong!

Comment: I can see why they write it that way because the term character is so loaded with different meanings.

Comment: I used TextOut(ps.hdc, 10, 100, tx, 2); and it didn't work. Two question marks (invalid glyphs) are printed.

Comment: I've tried both TextOut() and ExtTextOut(), both with 1 and 2 "characters". Both functins returned TRUE, but they always exhibit one, or two, invalid glyphs.

Comment: Are you calling `TextOutW()` and `ExtTextOutW()`? You must call the Unicode versions.

Comment: I'm calling TextOutW() and ExtTextOutW() since I'm using an UNICODE build.

Comment: My knowledge of surrogate pairs is limited.  Does 0xD835 0xDC00 really translate to U+1D400?  Any endian issues?

Comment: You can apply [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates) to check it out